# SubQuery retornando valor nulo

Tags: sql, informix

Estou fazendo essa query, e preciso consultar o valor de custo de um produto utilizando uma subquery, pois a tabela de nota é a mesma de entrada e saída. Os produtos não repetem. O que diferencia venda e custo. É a série da nota. Está retornando o custo como nulo. Porém se eu incluir um código de produto manualmente. Ele funciona.

Estrutua:
`mercadoria = varchar(12)`

```
SELECT *, 
(select valornota from nota as u inner 
join itemnota as j 
on u.id_nfcapa = j.id_nfcapa 
where j.mercadoria = i.mercadoria and u.serienf = '001') as custo
FROM nota as n 
inner join itemnota as i on n.id_nfcapa = i.id_nfcapa 
WHERE n.datanf BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31'
AND n.serie = '1'
```

Assim funciona:

```
SELECT *, 
(select valornota from nota as u inner 
join itemnota as j 
on u.id_nfcapa = j.id_nfcapa 
where j.mercadoria = 'PROD1234' and u.serienf = '001') as custo
FROM nota as n 
inner join itemnota as i on n.id_nfcapa = i.id_nfcapa 
WHERE n.datanf BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31'
AND n.serie = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve especificar quais são os campos do resultset. Tente com a modificação abaixo:

```
SELECT i.mercadoria, custo 
 (select valornota from nota as u 
  inner join itemnota as j 
  on u.id_nfcapa = j.id_nfcapa 
  where j.mercadoria = u.mercadoria and u.serienf = '001') as custo
 FROM nota as n 
 inner join itemnota as i on n.id_nfcapa = i.id_nfcapa 
 WHERE n.datanf BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31'
 AND n.serie = '1'
```

Comment: Rodai exatamente a sua SQL, só tirei o campo custo. Esse campo não existe na tabela. Ele é um alias da subquery. Retornou esse erro:  A subquery has returned not exactly one row.

Comment: Realmente o campo custo nao existe na tabela. Ele é apenas um alias. Você precisa inserir o nome do campo correspondente em na tabela itemnota. Qual é a estrutura das tabelas ?

Comment: mercadoria = Varchar(12)

Comment: Eduardo, para esclarecer sua dúvida é importante ter informações sobre a estrutura de campos das tabelas envolvidas, assim torna-se possível reproduzir a situação que encontrou.

Comment: Consegui resolver amigo, tirei o apelido das tabelas. Utilizei no formato TABELA.CAMPO sem usar inner join. Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Fico feliz em saber disso, Eduardo. Happy programming!